# Multiple updates with 1 submit Laravel

Tags: php

I want make multiple updates with 1 submit button in Laravel. I use Laravel 9 and I read some guides, but nothing work.
This is my blade html file...

```
<form method="post" action="/adminpanel/charclass">
                                    {{csrf_field()}}
 @foreach($char as $values)
                                   <tr>

                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-4">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="id[]" value="{{$values->id}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="classname[]" value="{{$values->classname}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="shortname[]" value="{{$values->shortname}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="maxlevel[]" value="{{$values->maxlevel}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="col-8">
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ppl[]" value="{{$values->ppl}}">
                                        </div>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                @endforeach
<div class="card-footer">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-12">Submit</button>
                        </div>
                            </form>
```

And this is controler

```
 foreach ($request->id as $key => $items)
{

    $update = DB::connection('XWEB')->table('XWEB_CHARCLASS')
        ->where('id', $request->id[$key])
        ->update(
            [

                'classname' => $request->classname[$key],
                'shortname' => $request->shortname[$key],
                'maxlevel' => $request->maxlevel[$key],
                'ppl' => $request->ppl[$key]
            ]);

    return redirect('adminpanel/charclass');
}

}
```

But its not working ...... Any advice will be appreciated .. Thanks in advance

Comment: you are creating a form for each record (and you don't even close the form tag). You should create 1 single form (outside the @foreach loop)

Comment: I have </form> after foreach and after submit button

Comment: But you still have the _opening_ `<form>` tag inside the loop. And since forms can't be nested in HTML, the parser will automatically close the currently open form, when it encounters another opening form tag.

Comment: @CBroe I edited code and still dont work. Now opening <form> tag is outside and close tag is after loop. Look first post.

Comment: So what data does actually get send, when you submit this? Use your browser dev tools, network panel, to find out.

Comment: @CBroe when i use dd($request->id[$key]) i get only "1" and i can edit only the first result.

Comment: That's not what I asked you to check.

Comment: @CBroe https://i.imgur.com/iywS8Tq.png give me all results and new edit but in sql still stay old. I change Dark Wizard to Dark Wizard5, but in sql is Dark Wizard

Comment: You got a 500 Internal Server Error there, so go check what the error log has to say.

Comment: @CBroe https://i.imgur.com/DT9Dabt.png & https://i.imgur.com/S8J8Sgh.png 
This is from error log when i click on 500 Internal Server Error. How i can fix it?

Comment: This is not the PHP error log, this is just the browser console showing the same 500 Internal Server Error - which is just a generic status code, that is not supposed to give too much information away to outside parties. You need to go and check the actual PHP error log, and find out the _reason_ for this error.

Comment: @CBroe where i can visit my PHP error log?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5127838/1427878